# Java - programa simples (achar primos) - não roda

Tags: java

Estou começando aprender java, estou usando o livro Java a *Beguinners Guide* e apareceu esse probleminha para encontrar os primos de 1 - 100 e imprimir na tela. Fiz o seguinte código.

```
class AllPrime {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i;
        int counter = 0;
        int k;

        for(i = 1; 1 <= 100; i++)
        {
            for(k = 1; k <= i; k++)
            {
                if( (i % k) == 0)
                    ++counter;  
            }
            if( counter == 2 )
                System.out.println("The number: " + i + "is prime");
        }
    }
}
```

Não imprimiu nada na tela. Já li e reli esse código e não consigo entender o que está errado. Ele compila só não roda.

Comment: So relembrando que um primo só divide por ele mesmo e um, por isso o counter == 2

Comment: Tenta colocar o ++ no lado direito da variável conter

Comment: Falta fazer reset à variavel counter após o if(counter == 2)

Answer (score 6):

Você cometeu uns pequenos erros bobos.

- O seu grande erro é que você não faz o `counter` voltar para zero depois de iterar um número no `i`. Por causa disso, após decidir que 1 não é primo, ele nunca mais será capaz de decidir que número nenhum é primo, uma vez que `counter` nunca diminui.
- Outro probleminha era a condição de parada do `for` que estava `1 <= 100` ao invés de `i <= 100`.
- Por fim, você pode declarar as variáveis `i` e `k` dentro do próprio `for`, não precisa declarar antes.
- Faltou acrescentar um espaço antes do `"is prime"`.

Assim, aqui está o seu código corrigido.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
                if (i % k == 0) ++counter;
            }
            if (counter == 2) {
                System.out.println("The number: " + i + " is prime");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Também é possível otimizar o seu código um pouco mais, pois você não precisa nunca testar se o número é divisível por 1 ou por ele mesmo, porque sempre será. Desta forma, você não precisará mais contar os divisores, pois assim que você acha um divisor já sabe que o número é composto e nem precisa perder tempo testando os demais números, podendo usar o `continue` para seguir para a próxima iteração. Isso também elimina a necessidade de haver a variável `counter`. Desta forma, o seu código fica assim:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        out: for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            for (int k = 2; k < i; k++) {
                if (i % k == 0) continue out;
            }
            System.out.println("The number: " + i + " is prime");
        }
    }
}
```

Dá para otimizar ainda mais se você verificar que se o número é composto, então pelo menos um dos divisores é menor ou igual a raiz quadrada do número. Assim, se até chegar na raiz quadrada, você não encontrar nenhum divisor, é porque o número é primo. Logo:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        out: for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            for (int k = 2; k <= Math.sqrt(i); k++) {
                if (i % k == 0) continue out;
            }
            System.out.println("The number: " + i + " is prime");
        }
    }
}
```

Há outros truques matemáticos possíveis, em especial para evitar testar valores de `k` que são compostos e também para computar a raiz quadrada inteira que é mais rápido que a raiz quadrada de ponto flutuante. Outras propriedades de números primos e compostos podem ser utilizadas para reduzir-se o esforço computacional. Entretanto, estas otimizações mais agressivas já não seriam simples, e você provavelmente quer um algoritmo que seja bem simples, ainda mais que você só está testando os primos até o número 100.

Comment: Para otimizar mais ainda da para usar `for (int k = 2; k < sqrt(i); k++)`

Comment: @Rcoster Tem razão. Muito obrigado. Resposta editada..

Answer (score 3):

O erro esta no fato de que você não esta reiniciando o valor da variável `counter` para cada `i`.

Veja:

- O código inicia com `counter == 0`.
- Quando `i == 1` e `k == 1`, `i % k == 0`. Logo, `counter++` (`counter == 1`).
- `k` é incrementado, e sai do `for`.
- Quando `i == 2` e `k == 1`, `i % k == 0`. Logo, `counter++` (`counter == 2`).
- Quando `i == 2` e `k == 2`, `i % k == 0`. Logo, `counter++` (`counter == 3`).
- `k` é incrementado, e sai do `for`.

Repare que `counter > 2` (`counter == 3`). Por indução, nunca será impresso a mensagem, uma vez que `counter` irá apenas crescer e já ultrapassou o valor esperado para impressão da mensagem.

Reiniciando o valor de `counter` em cada iteração em `i` resolve o problema:

```
class AllPrime {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i;
        int k;

        for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            for(k = 1; k <= i; k++)
            {
                if( (i % k) == 0)
                    ++counter;  
            }
            if( counter == 2 )
                System.out.println("The number: " + i + "is prime");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer dessa forma, fazendo um método static isPrime, para que seu código fica mais simples, organizado e legível:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
           if (isPrime(i)) {
               System.out.println("The number: " + i + " is prime");
           }

        }

    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int x) {

       int count = 2;

       for (int i = 2; i < x; i++) {
          if (x % i == 0) {
              count++;
          }
       }

       return count == 2;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementando as respostas anteriores, que diga-se de passagem já estão mais do que completas, gostaria de deixar um exemplo em que você tenha a possibilidade de deixar o seu código um pouco mais flexível, onde você mesmo possa determinar o intervalo em que queira verificar todos os números primos, além de te proporcionar mais uma maneira de visualizar outras perspectivas sobre esse problema.

```
import java.io.*;

public class AllPrime {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int minimo;
        int maximo;

        System.out.println("****************************");
        System.out.println("Digite um intervalo: ");
        System.out.println("****************************");

        System.out.println("\nMinimo: ");
        minimo = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

        System.out.println("\nMaximo: ");
        maximo = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

        for (int i = minimo; i <= maximo; i++)
            if (isPrime(i)) imprimir(i);

    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
        int count = 2;

        for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
           if (number % i == 0) {
               count++;
           }
        }
        return count == 2;
    }

    public static void imprimir (int number) {
        System.out.println("The number: " + number + " is prime");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Digite um numero:");
    int numero = scan.nextInt();

    int diferença = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < numero; i++) {

        if (numero % i == 0) {
            diferença ++;
        }
    }

    if (diferença == 1) {
        System.out.println(numero +  " É Primo");
    }else {
        System.out.println(numero + " Não é primo");
    }
}
```

Comment: Respostas, apenas com código, sem nenhuma explicação não se enquadram no objectivo do Stackoverflow