# Ajuda com algoritmo de "n" numeros primos em uma ArrayList

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, algoritmo, arraylist

[image]

Por favor preciso de ajuda urgente,como arrumar o meu código? toda hora que eu chamo o metodo da o erro da direita,eu sou iniciante e estou travado em um exercicio que requer numeros primos baseado em um numero n(nesse caso o this.n),por exemplo o numero é 20,deve retornar uma ArrayList com os 20 primeiros numeros primos(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71),preciso do codigo usando for-each

Comment: Veja mais como encontrar números primos [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97005/java-programa-simples-achar-primos-não-roda).

Comment: Você pode colar seu código aqui, ao invés dessa imagem?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda e paciencia.

Comment: Boa sorte... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu `contador++` está fora do `while` - isso significa que o código abaixo executará *para sempre*:

```
contador++; // estou fora do while!
while(contador < this.n) // contador sempre será menor que this.n
    aux.add(i); // acaba com a memória heap adicionando i em aux eternamente
```

Para resolver isso, utilize chaves no loop while e no loop for:

```
for (;;) {
    // código aqui
}

while() {
    // código aqui
}
```

Usando o seu código:

```
while(contador < this.n) {
    aux.add(i);
    contador++; // agora contador eventualmente será maior que this.n
}
```

---

> [Utilizando a resposta do @VictorStafusa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/97011/4816), segue uma possível solução:

**Primos.java:**

```
public class Primos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumeroInteiro n = new NumeroInteiro(20);
        for (int i : n.getPrimos()) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

**NumeroInteiro.java:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumeroInteiro {
    private int n = 0;

    public NumeroInteiro(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getPrimos() {

        ArrayList<Integer> aux = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; aux.size() < this.n; i++) {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {
                if (i % k == 0)
                    ++counter;
            }
            if (counter == 2) {
                aux.add(i);
            }
        }
        return aux;
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**
[image: lista de primos gerada pelo programa]

Comment: Pode me ajudar com o resto do código?,o método está apenas retornando o numero 2 20 vezes(quando this.n = 20)

Comment: @JohnSchultz viu o link que eu postei acima?

Comment: Sim,poderia me ajudar como a arrumar meu código usando os nomes das minhas variaveis,é que ver o código com outros nomes e métodos diferentes me deixou confuso

Comment: @JohnSchultz nem mexi no algoritmo - foi *copy&paste* da outra resposta - da uma olhada na minha edição.